How to Ensure AVPlayer or VideoPlayer Content Fills the Entire Available Space in SwiftUI?
I’m working on a SwiftUI application and I’m trying to display a video using AVPlayer. I need to ensure that the video content completely fills the available space without leaving any empty areas or having content cut off unintentionally. I’ve explored a few approaches but have not yet achieved the desired result. Here’s a summary of what I have tried so far:

Using AVPlayerViewController with UIViewRepresentable:
I created a UIViewControllerRepresentable to use AVPlayerViewController in SwiftUI:

import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let player: AVPlayer

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        controller.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {}
}

In the AVPlayerViewController, setting videoGravity to .resizeAspectFill was supposed to make the video content fill the entire view, but it didn’t work as expected in terms of adjusting the content’s position.

Using VideoPlayer Library:
I also tried using the VideoPlayer library for a more SwiftUI-friendly approach:

import SwiftUI
import VideoPlayer

struct CustomVideoPlayerView: View {
    @State private var player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "xxxx", withExtension: "mp4")!)

    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) // Adjust the video to fill the space
            .frame(height: 300)
            .clipped() // Ensure the video does not exceed the visible area
            .onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                player.pause()
                player.seek(to: .zero)
            }
    }
}

The aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) approach was intended to make the video fill the available space, but I still faced issues ensuring that the video content completely covers the space without unintended empty areas or content clipping.
Problem:
The video content does not consistently fill the entire available space as needed. I want the video to fully occupy the specified area, similar to how AVPlayerLayer with .resizeAspectFill would work but directly within a SwiftUI context.
What I’m Seeking:

A method or approach to ensure the video content fills the entire available space in SwiftUI.
Solutions that provide similar functionality to AVPlayerLayer’s .resizeAspectFill but within SwiftUI or using VideoPlayer.

If anyone has experience with achieving precise control over video content in SwiftUI or can suggest alternative methods, I would greatly appreciate your guidance!
Feel free to modify or expand on this description based on your specific needs or any additional context you think is important.
Here's the actual
What I’m Seeking

SwiftUI is state-driven by value types, you need to remove the procedural player.play() and player.pause() and pass a let isPlaying: Bool value to your VideoPlayerView struct and implement updateUIViewController to use the value of isPlaying to either call play() or pause(). updateUIViewController is like the transformation layer between SwiftUI's state-driven and UIKit's procedural.

@malhal
got it, but i cant see how this helps with the question about show the content filled and with the correct position. Could you explain to me please?

By adding aspect ratio to the video player, you can achieve a full view of the video. I have set the aspect ratio to 1:2, which displays perfectly. Please ensure that the aspect ratio is set up to work on all devices.
import SwiftUI
import VideoPlayer

struct CustomVideoPlayerView: View {
    @State private var player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "xxxx", withExtension: "mp4")!)

    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .aspectRatio(1/2, contentMode: .fill) //  Hang it here according to your needs.
            .frame(height: 300)
            .clipped() // Ensure the video does not exceed the visible area
            .onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                player.pause()
                player.seek(to: .zero)
            }
    }
}

Without aspect ratio screenshot
With aspect ratio screenshot

Including the modifier aspectRatio, the content inside filled component but it centralized and clipped the header of the video. Should i adjust and find the aspectRatio with GeometryReader or has another way to just move the center point of the content to show the right place?

Maybe try creating your own view using UIViewRepresentable api.
Something like this:
public struct AVPlayerViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    public typealias ActionVoid = (() -> ())
    let touchesBegan: ActionVoid?
    let player: AVPlayer

    public init(_ player: AVPlayer, touchesBegan: ActionVoid?) {
        self.player = player
        self.touchesBegan = touchesBegan
    }
    
    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> AVPlayerLayerUIView {
        let view = AVPlayerLayerUIView(touchesBegan: touchesBegan)
        view.playerLayer.player = player
        return view
    }
    
    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: AVPlayerLayerUIView, context: Context) {
        uiView.playerLayer.player = player
    }
}

public class AVPlayerLayerUIView: UIView {
    public typealias ActionVoid = (() -> ())
    let touchesBegan: ActionVoid?

    public override class var layerClass: AnyClass { AVPlayerLayer.self }
    public var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer { layer as? AVPlayerLayer ?? .init(layer: layer) }

    public init(touchesBegan: ActionVoid?) {
        self.touchesBegan = touchesBegan
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        backgroundColor = .black
    }
    
    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        touchesBegan?()
    }
}

